# How to create a CNAME url redirect with Google DNS?

Tags: redirect, dns, cname

The problem is, whenever I input the following string into the "data" table for a CNAME on Google Domains DNS services:

`forms.office.com.opts-slash.pages.opts-slash.responsepage.aspx.opts-query.nfsd2rcrknewwv3eonlta6lyivvgc2scjrnhi4srifaucqkbifaucqkbifau2qkbjrgecmleijku6rlqivkdanbvkfvec6snnjexuuswjf3vgvksljkvkzzvkzweuvsokm2hk.opts-https.redirect.center.`

It responds with "Invalid Data". However, I have successfully set up a CNAME redirect for a discord invite link by using:

`discord.gg.opts-slash.INVITECODE.redirect.center.`

Why is it saying that the forms.office data is invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your name is not valid per DNS rules.

Its full lenght is 236 which is ok as the limit is 255 (and 253 in practice).

But the DNS rules also mandates that each label (each string between dots) is at most 63 bytes (characters here for your case) long.

You have one label being `nfsd2rcrknewwv3eonlta6lyivvgc2scjrnhi4srifaucqkbifaucqkbifau2qkbjrgecmleijku6rlqivkdanbvkfvec6snnjexuuswjf3vgvksljkvkzzvkzweuvsokm2hk` which is 134 characters long, far over the 63 limit, so your name is not valid and can not be used in the DNS.